# Java random array of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am trying to make an array of random numbers that range from 0-9 with the variable for this one being kickerNumbers.  I get a compile error though saying incompatible types.  I have tried changing the `(int)` to `[int]` like it said but I didn't think that would be right anyway and surly enough it wasn't.  Is there another way to write this?  I need it to act as the first four numbers of this to be 0-9 but the fifth number would need to be something smaller such as 0-4.  for the 0-4 one I just made that a completely different variable.  Was that a good choice? Here is the sample code for the lines that give the error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class CashBallTest
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int kicker;
        int[] kickerNumbers = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);
        int kickerPowerball=(int)(Math.random()*0+4);
```

The error reads:

```
\CashBallTest.java:9: incompatible types
    found   : int
    required: int[]
    int[] kickerNumbers = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);
```

I have also tried changing `(int)` to `(int[])` but then it said it was an inconvertible type counting as a double when it needs to be an `int[]` but I don't see where it gets the double type from.

Answer (score 7):

```
int[] kickerNumbers = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);
```

You can't assign an `int` to an `int[]`

Assuming that is supposed to be more the one number, it might be something like this

```
int[] kickerNumbers = new int[5];
for(int i = 0; i < kickerNumbers.length; i++) {
    kickerNumbers[i] = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);
}
```

On an unrelated note, why are you multiplying the `Math.random()*0`? That seems silly to me. If you want a number 1 through 10, I would do this: `Math.random()*10 + 1`

Comment: +1 for pointing out the random() issue. (and posting before me :) )

Answer (score 4):

1. This is an int array: `int[] kickerNumbers` but you assign it with int (not array) `(int)(Math.random()*0+9);`
2. your random will return 9. **always** (operator precedence).

Create an array like this: `int[] kickerNumbers = int[numberOfPlayers]` and assign numbers in loop, or use ArrayList with numbers from 0-9 and call `shuffle`

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

```
java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
int[] kickerNumbers = r.ints(0, 10).limit(5).toArray(); // 5 times 0...9
```

Then change last element:

```
kickerNumbers[4] = r.nextInt(5);
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be work using your own random number generator so you can use nextInt and avoid some confusion.

```
Random r = new Random();
// four values [0, 9]
int[] kickerNumbers={r.nextInt(10), r.nextInt(10), r.nextInt(10), r.nextInt(10)};
// one value [0, 4]
int kickerPowerball = r.nextInt(5);
```

Comment: +1 for `r.nextInt()`. better than the games with `Math.random()`

Comment: And faster, but that doesn't matter here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to assign an int to an array which is what is giving you the error.

what you want to do it use a loop to iterate through your array and assign random values to it, you mentioned that you wanted your numbers to be between 0-9 and 0-4 the following code will give you that result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] kickerNumbers = new int[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < kickerNumbers.length; i++) {
        kickerNumbers[i] = randomRange(0,9);
    }
    int kickerPowerball = randomRange(0,4);
}
public static int randomRange(int min, int max) {
    return (int) Math.round(((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min));
}
```

the code above includes a method that will return a integer between to given parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;
public class CashBallTest {

    public static void main (String[]args){

        int[] kickerNumbers= new int[5];
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
            kickerNumbers[i]=randomize(9);
            kickerNumbers[4]=randomize(4);

        for (int i:kickerNumbers)
            System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static int  randomize(int k){
        Random rand=new Random();
        return rand.nextInt(k);
    }
}
```

Assuming you don't care for duplicates.

Sorry. I had not read answer from Peter... It is just the same.

Comment: You also should *not* get a `new Random()` every time.